# AS3 timer currentCount value

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, countdown

> **Edit**

I'm trying countdown timer. I need to current count value. I want to reach outside the function

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

var count:int = 10;
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,count);
var ev:TimerEvent = new TimerEvent(TimerEvent.TIMER);
myTimer.dispatchEvent(ev);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
myTimer.start();
var number1:int;
var number2:int;
mytxt.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,rest);
function countdown(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    number1 = count - myTimer.currentCount;
    slr(number1);
}

function slr(s:int)
{
    if (s>5)
    {
        mytxt.restrict = "a";
        trace("a");
    }
    if (s<5)
    {
        mytxt.restrict = "b";
        trace("b");
    }

}
function rest(evt:Event)
{
    if (mytxt.text == "a")
{
    mytxt.restrict = "";
}
else if (mytxt.text=="b")
{
    mytxt.restrict = "";
}
}
```

I want to only once "a" key press in the first 5 second. and only once "b" key press in the second 5 second

Comment: What's the need to have two variables? number1/2? Why not only one?

Answer (score 0):

Currently `number2` is going to get set immediately. This is more what I believe you are looking  for:

```
//set this under your myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
```

Then add this function:

```
function onTimerComplete( e:TimerEvent ):void {
    number2 = number1; 
    trace("number2 :"+number2);
}
```